# Get non-scam assets via Bybit API

Tags: bybit

I want to use the API to find approximately 100 coins with the highest capitalization in order to prevent the purchase of scam coins. I can't find a suitable method in the API. It might be worth considering ranking by daily trading volasddsume. What is the appropriate method to use?

Comment: Capitalization doesn't indicate non scam coin. Shitcoin can has large supply that leads to huge capitalization. Daily trading volume too. Marketmakers with bots can wind up it.